# Find NaN values in a certain column of a matrix and return the cell location

Tags: matlab, matrix

As the title suggests I am trying to find the location of NaN numbers in a matrix.
At the moment I have a matrix size of <15000x20>. I want to check one coulmn of this and return the locations of values with NaN in them.

This is what I have so far, but it seems ot always return blank.

```
Input = xlsread('data.xlsx');
TF = isnan(Input); 

prompt = 'Which column to check?  ';
column = input(prompt)

empty = 0;

for i = 1:length(Input)

   empty = find(TF(i, column) == 1)

end
```

It always returns an empty matrix, not the locations like it should. I know that it has found the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find(isnan(data(:,column)))` should do the trick for you.

Here is the full script I used to generate the data

```
% To create the data. You can read from excel file.
rows = 100;
cols = 5;
data = randi(10000,[rows,cols]);
for i=1:(rows*cols/25)
    data(randi(rows*cols)) = NaN;
end

% Take user prompt
prompt = 'Which column to check?  ';
column = input(prompt);

% Calculate result
nans = find(isnan(data(:,column)));
```